# <select> tag in html for creating a dropdown list of options

Tags: html, frontend

why is my select tag in my html form not working. this is my code.

```
<div>
<h3>Data Source</h3>
<p>Specify the Primary Data Source for the list or charts</p>
<label for="records">Records :</label>
<select name="Related Records" id="Related Records"></select>
<option value="Only Related Records">Only Related Records</option>
<option value="Some Records">Some Records</option>
<option value="Casual Records">Casual Records</option>
<option value="Specific Records">Specific Records</option>
<option value="Important Records">Important Records</option>
```

in the form the select button is not working

I expected the select button to work and create a dropdown list consisting of the options.

but that is not happening....

Answer (score 0):

The `option`s of a `select` need to be children of that select tag:

```html
<label for="records">Records :</label>
<select name="Related Records" id="Related Records">
    <option value="Only Related Records">Only Related Records</option>
    <option value="Some Records">Some Records</option>
    <option value="Casual Records">Casual Records</option>
    <option value="Specific Records">Specific Records</option>
    <option value="Important Records">Important Records</option>
// move closing tag to end:
</select>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

you closed select tag before option-

see this-

```
<select name="Related Records" id="Related Records">
<option value="Only Related Records">Only Related Records</option>
<option value="Some Records">Some Records</option>
<option value="Casual Records">Casual Records</option>
<option value="Specific Records">Specific Records</option>
<option value="Important Records">Important Records</option>
</select>
```